# How do I access android.os.storage.IMountService?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm working on a custom tablet running Android 6.0.1. I have root access and have placed the app I'm making in the **/system/priv-app/** directory and thus gaining access to system permissions.

This app needs to copy files from the sdcard partition to a flash drive (The tablet I'm working on has 2 Full USB ports) and then unmount the flash drive.

I've already got the file's being copied successfully, but im having trouble unmounting the flash drive.

From what I've read I need access to the **android.os.storage.IMountService** class.

How do i go about this?

I've tried adding a classes-full-debug.jar file I found online but there were errors when trying to compile in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the library **SDK/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/framework_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar** to my app after compiling android.

Android studio will complain about an out of memory error, this is fixed by adding the below code to the build.gradle inside the android section.

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

You also need to add multidex support by adding the below lines in build.gradle inside the defaultConfig section.

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

And adding the below line inside the dependencies section.

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

And adding the below line in the application section inside the manifest.

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

And your app has to be in the **/system/priv-app** directory and have the below permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE" />
```